# What is the difference between mwc.js and mwc.esm.js?

Tags: javascript, module, electron, stenciljs

I created a StencilJS project that has a bunch of web components bundled in my **mwc** project.  From within Stencil, I can execute `npm run start` and see my components working as expected.

I created an Electron project and in it I'm importing the stencil mwc package using :

```
<script src="dist/mwc/mwc.js"></script>
```

When I do this I've noticed the stencil generated code fails to run any for-loops that iterate over a **Map** or **Set**.  Basically the for-loop exits and never iterates.

For example, in one of my components I have a class that defines a variable this way:

```
private _groupedItems : Map<string, Item[]> = new Map();
```

This variable gets populated and when the following code tries to run, it always fails:

```
@Method()
async updateItemAsync( arg : { value : string, data : UpdateSelectItem } ) {
  //find where the item value is located
  let item : Item | undefined = undefined;
  for( const key of this._groupedItems.keys() ) {
    const groupedItems = this._groupedItems.get( key );
    if( groupedItems ) {
      item = groupedItems.find( item => item.value === arg.value );
      if( item ) {
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  if( item === undefined ) {
    console.error( 'Could not find item to update with value=', arg.value );
    return;
  }
  //NEVER GETS HERE!
  //more code below snipped out
}
```

In Chrome devTools I can see that the generated JavaScript that is trying to run looks like this:

```
e.prototype.updateItemAsync = function(e) {
  return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function() {
    var t, i, n, r, s;
    return __generator(this, function(a) {
      t = undefined;
      for (i = 0,
           n = this._groupedItems.keys(); i < n.length; i++) {
        r = n[i];
        s = this._groupedItems.get(r);
        if (s) {
          t = s.find(function(t) {
          return t.value === e.value
        });
        if (t) {
          break
        }
      }
    }
    if (t === undefined) {
      console.error("Could not find item to update with value=", e.value);
      return [2]
    }
```

I discovered if instead of using the aforementioned script, I use this instead :

```
<script type="module" src="dist/mwc/mwc.esm.js"></script>
```

Then everything works fine (*sort of*).  Basically when I fire up my Electron package using webpack all the code works as expected and my for-loops are now working.  The problem with this solution is that when I package my Electron application using electron-webpack, I can't run the resulting standalone EXE because I get an error message when the application starts up.  Chrome gives me an error when it tries to load the mwc.esm.js file:

```
Failed to load module script: The server responded with a non-JavaScript MIME type of "". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

What is the difference between the mwc.js and mwc.esm.js files?  Why won't the mwc.js file run my for-loops properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `esm.js` file is a [Javascript Module](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) which will be served to browsers that support it.

When you use the old way of including a Stencil component (`/dist/mwc.js`) you will get a console warning about how to properly include it, which is also documented [in the breaking changes](https://github.com/ionic-team/stencil/blob/master/BREAKING_CHANGES.md#indexhtmls-scripts-updated-to-use-typemodule) for version 1:

```
[mwc] Deprecated script, please remove: <script src="/dist/mwc.js"></script>
To improve performance it is recommended to set the differential scripts in the head as follows:
<script type="module" src="/dist/mwc/mwc.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="/dist/mwc/mwc.js"></script>
```

I don't know why `Map` and `Set` loops would not work with the non-module file but the module is the recommended way of importing in Chrome.

The MIME type error seems to be [a known issue in Electron](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12011) which seems to be because Electron uses the `file://` protocol by default which doesn't allow including modules, as per spec.